# Como usar TextWatcher con EditText

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de implementar una app que se solo acepte números hexadecimales y cada 4 números hexadecimales debe de insertar una espacio, he logrado hacer este por separado usando TextWatcher por separado, pero no logro hacer ambas funciones en un solo TextWatcher, por favor alguien me podria indicar como hacerlo.

Aquí están los dos TextWatcher:

Este TextWatcher solo acepta como entrada de edittext números hexadecimales

```
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String str = s.toString();
                if (str.isEmpty()) {
                    mTextoEditor2.append(newStr);
                    newStr = "";
                } else if (!str.equals(newStr)) {
                    newStr = str.replaceAll("[^A-F0-9a-f]", "");
                    mTextoEditor2.setText("");
                }
            }
```

Este otro inserta un espacio cada cuatro caracteres ingresados por edittext

```
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (count == 4)
                {
                    mTextoEditor2.setText(mTextoEditor2.getText()+" ");
                    mTextoEditor2.setSelection(mTextoEditor2.getText().length());
                }
            }
```

Necesito unir ambos en un solo TextWatcher, alguien me podria decir como hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podés usar este código con el string completo del edit text.

Quita los caracteres que no son hexadecimales.
Quita espacio agregados antes.
Recalcula los espacios.
Pone todo en mayúsculas.

`s` es el texto de entrada y `out` el texto de salida:

```
    String s = "ABc1 2369 JRDf89Yt78";

    s = s.replaceAll("[^a-f|A-F|0-9]", "");
    s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");
    String out = "";
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        if(i>0 && i%4 == 0) {
            out+=" ";
        }
        out+=s.charAt(i);
    }
    out = out.trim().toUpperCase();
```

`out` queda como: `ABC1 2369 DF89 78` en el ejemplo.

El método a utilizar en el `TextWatcher` es `afterTextChanged(Editable editable)`.

Como cuando se cambia el texto del `EditText` en este método, se vuelve a llamar al `TextWatecher` generando un un loop infinito, le agrego un la variable `ignorar` al `TextWatcher` y la pongo en true cuando el texto lo estoy cambiando desde el método.

```
etEjemplo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private boolean ignorar = false;
        private long ultimaCorrida = -1;
        private String textoOriginal="";

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            long estaCorrida = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (!ignorar) {
                ignorar = true;
                String s = editable.toString();
                //editable.clear();
                if (estaCorrida - ultimaCorrida > 50) {
                    s = s.replaceAll("[^a-f|A-F|0-9]", "");
                    s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");
                    String out = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                        if (i > 0 && i % 4 == 0) {
                            out += " ";
                        }
                        out += s.charAt(i);
                    }
                    out = out.trim().toUpperCase();

                    //editable.append(out);
                    etEjemplo.setText(out);
                    textoOriginal = out;
                    ultimaCorrida = estaCorrida;
                } else {
                    //editable.append(textoOriginal);
                    etEjemplo.setText(textoOriginal);
                }
                etEjemplo.setSelection(etEjemplo.getText().length());
                ignorar = false;
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: Tal Vez no me he dejado entender, el edittex solo debe de permitir ingresar números hexadecimales, si el usuario presiona alguna tecla diferente simplemente en el edittext no debe de mostrar ese carácter, la cadena de caracteres a ingresar es ilimitado, en el primer TextWatchers, que he publicado puedo hacer esto y en el segundo puedo insertar los espacios en blanco, ahora necesito unir ambas funcionalidades en uno solo...

Comment: he probado tu codigo en mi app y no me funciona, no hay cambio en las caracteres ingresados, talvez me podrias mostrar un ejemplo completo?

Comment: Ahi agregué el ejemplo.

Comment: Usando tu codigo tengo esta respuesta, no filtra los números hexadecimales y tampoco mantiene la secuencia de un espacio cada 4 números [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.postimg.cc/dQbBFwKZ/ezgif-com-video-to-gif-1.gif

Comment: El código lo corrí y hace las dos cosas. Si querés agrega el código tuyo actualizado y lo vemos.

Comment: Por las dudas fijate si tenes esta linea **s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");** que la agregué un poco despues de pegar la solución la primera vez.

Comment: Colgue tu código actualizado al inicio, no funciona, no se cual puede ser el error?

Comment: Lo pusiste en onTextChanged, y va en afterTextChanged. y no veo la declaración de boolean ignorar. Tendiria que esta despues de new TextWatcher(){ (o lo que es lo mismo, donde está en mi ejemplo arriba del @Override del metodo.)

Comment: Cuando lo pases a afterTextChanged, fijate como está mi ejemplo. Vos le cambiaste cosas porque el metodo no tiene el Editable.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85560/discussion-between-w1ll-and-juan).

Comment: Actualizado y probado en Moto G y Samsung S4.